# AttributeError - When using Django NestedFields serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've 2 models:-

```
class Users(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class UserAddress(models.Model):
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users)
```

The user model  & user address model. Following are the 2 serializers.

```
class UserAddressSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserAddress
        exclude = ('id', 'user')


class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    address = UserAddressSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        address = validated_data.pop('address', [])
        user = Users.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for ad in address:
            UserAddress.objects.create(user=user, **ad)

        return user
```

The data I receive from the client is

```
{
  "first_name": "string",
  "last_name": "string",
  "address": [{
     "line1": "asd",
     "country": "asd",
  }],
}
```

This is how I create a new user and its corresponding address.

```
class UserCreate(GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        data = request.data
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return

        user = serializer.save()
        response = {
            'user_id': user.uuid
        }
        return
```

Now, upon getting the user details back, I receive an error saying

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `address` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Users` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Users' object has no attribute 'address'.
```

This is how I get the details of the user, including the address.

```
class UserDetails(GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Users.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'uuid'

    def get(self, request, uuid, *args, **kwargs):
        user = Users.get_user(uuid)
        if not user:
            return 

        serializer = UserSerializer(instance=user)
        return
```

I'd read [this example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example) of nested relationship, and am doing exactly the same way. why is the error coming up?

**Also, can this code be shorten up more (in a nicer clean way) using some DRF mixins? If yes, then how?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most simple solution for your case is: in model `UserAddress` add `related_name='address'`

```
class UserAddress(models.Model):
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, related_name='address')
    #                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or you can add sourse property in serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    address = UserAddressSerializer(source='useraddress_set', many=True)
```

Serializer try to find attribute 'address' in the model `User`, but by default it is  modelname underscore set (`useraddress_set` in your case), and you try other name, so you can set in the model or specify by source.

in the example you can look on [models](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#api-reference) and find the `related_name='tracks'`

Comment: Great!! Works like a charm. Thanks @Bear.

Comment: glad to help you!

Comment: Also, could you also recommend, if et all its possible, to write a much better code using DRF. Basically these CRUD operations.

Comment: may be you can use [modelviewset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) instead of two times GenericAPIView.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast You should accept the answer to let future searchers know it solved your problem.